# How do I create an additional jlink artifact on my jar project?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Using the [maven-jlink-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jlink-plugin/), I want to create an additional jlink zip file.

I have configured it like so:

```
<profile>
  <id>jlink</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- to be able to package the application using jlink, all dependencies MUST have a module-info.java. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jlink-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-runtime-image</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jlink</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <launcher>memeforcehunt=memeforcehunt.app/io.github.alttpj.memeforcehunt.app.cli.MemeforceHuntApp
              </launcher>
              <modulePaths>
                <modulePath>${project.build.directory}/modules</modulePath>
              </modulePaths>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

But when I try to execute `mvn package -Pjlink`, I get an error message: There is already an artifact attached to the project.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  34.657 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-17T14:33:04+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jlink-plugin:3.0.0:jlink (create-runtime-image) on project memeforce-app: You have to use a classifier to attach supplemental artifacts to the project instead of replacing them. -> [Help 1]
```

But I cannot add a classifier to the jlink-plugin?

#### Tag request

`maven-jlink-plugin` => [maven-jlink-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-jlink-plugin)

Comment: please create the tag [maven-jlink-plugin], thanks. More questions incoming due to new release!

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue, reported in [MJLINK-49](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJLINK-49) and [MJLINK-26](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJLINK-26), and solved via [MJLINK-52 - classifier support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJLINK-52). This will be available in version 3.1.0.

### Solution for the upcoming 3.1.0 version

Just add a classifier. It will be supported.

### Workaround for pre-3.1.0 versions

However, you can create the archive using a workaround.
Change your packaging to `<packaging>jlink</packaging>` and add a jar execution:

```
<packaging>jlink</packaging>

<!-- … -->

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>create-jar</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <classifier>appjar</classifier>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  <plugins>
</build>
```

You will get two artifacts out of your project:

```
groupId:artifactId:version:jlink
```

and

```
groupId:artifactId:version:jar:appjar
```

Please note that the jar will now have a classifier.

#### Tag request

`maven-jlink-plugin` => [maven-jlink-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-jlink-plugin)